# Using wireless keyboard with trackball with Ubuntu

Tags: wireless, keyboard

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04 on an old ThinkPad, but I would really like to utilise a Shintaro wireless keyboard with a trackball with Ubuntu.

The keyboard features are all working but I can't seem to get the trackball working under Ubuntu. Does anyone know how I can get this working?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I know that the app QJoyPad and jstest-gtk work with joysticks, and can patch them into the system. Perhaps these two can help you get the trackball. Also, checking your Settings->Devices might help.

Comment: Unfortunately those options didn't solve.